# loading multiple modules in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, module

I'm constantly getting this error -

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=interactive-main

The project structure (with multiple people developing and all new to angularjs) looks like this -

```
public
   |--css, font-awesome
   |--js (where angular.min.js and other jquery libraries are)
   |--views (where html for each pages are)
        |--myHTMLcontents
        |--js
index.html
```

The index.html has it's own data-ng-app name and it's used in the app.js file.
I have my HTML files in the views folder, and the corresponding js files are in the views folder also.
I tried to create with

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(....
```

But I guess you're supposed to only create angular.module once (which is in the app.js), but I'm still unsure how to add 'myApp' in app.js.

I tried to do this:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('data-ng-app Name', [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'myApp'
    ])
})();
```

The nodejs server doesn't throw error, but nothing shows on the page (after I added 'myApp'). 
How do you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the module 'myApp' once and run it in app.js.
below is an example.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).run()
```

And then in your controller

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', []).controller('RegisterCtrl', function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

First make sure your declare the `myapp` module file in your index before inject it into an other one :

```
<script src="js/myapp.js"></script>
<script src="js/my-module-injecting-myapp.js"></script>
```

Then two ways : 
The first one is directly calling the module, by the way you did :

```
angular.module('myApp').controller(....
```

The second and what I used to do is declaring it as variable:

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

Then to declare a controller, service , whatever, just call the variable:

```
myAppModule.controller("myAppController", function(){...
```

One last thing, I don't know if was an example but do not declare your module name with space :

```
angular.module('data-ng-app Name', [....
```

should be :

```
angular.module('myModuleNamewithoutSpace', [....
```